# Sound device not accessible after starting Chromium

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, chromium

Whenever I start Chromium, sound playback from any application stops. If I go to Sound Settings, there is suddenly no device listed for sound output ("Play sound through").

Starting Chromium gives me the following errors:

```
$ chromium-browser
shm_open() failed: No such file or directory
[4410:4410:0330/135711.724364:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1019)] Lost UI shared context.
[1:18:0330/135711.892801:ERROR:adm_helpers.cc(73)] Failed to query stereo recording.
[4410:4444:0330/135712.484423:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[4410:4444:0330/135712.533962:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[4410:4444:0330/135712.625566:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
```

This is what sound settings looks like after starting Chromium:
[image]

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an x86_64 system than you should be able to run normal chrome instead of chromium, this may solve your sound problem. You can download google chrome here:
https://www.google.com/chrome/

Comment: I could do that. The thing is that Crome isn't open source, and I would rather like to stick with open source for a lot of reasons. It is why I chose Linux / Ubuntu in the first place. If you aren't into open source, then Chrome might be a better choice, among other things because of better flash support. More about the differences [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/).